# Toolbar subtitle is cut (It does not fit in height)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

My question is very simple, but i can't figure it out:

When i try to display a **subtitle**, **the toolbar** has not enough space do display it and it is cut.

**Toolbar:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
app:theme="@style/MyToolBar">
```

Does `?android:actionBarSize` have not enough height to display **title** and **subtitle** correctly?

When I set **ToolBar** height to `wrap_content` everything works, but can anyone explain to me how I should correctly set the height?

**styles.xml :**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background1</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="MyToolBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have used a toolbar with subtitles and as well as using a `layout_height="wrap_content"` I also add a `minHeight`.  This will ensure your toolbar is at least the minimum height.  I've not seen it jump in height or crop but I always have a subtitle set.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="@dimen/default_elevation"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Comment: now the back button is off vertical center when there's no subtitle

Answer (score 2):

I had used `layout_height=actionBarSize` for a long time even with subtitles present and never came across this issue (testing on various emulators and pixel phone). I applied this fix now after seeing my subtitle being cut-off on a Samsung Galaxy phone. Seems to me that this issue depends on how the system sets up the subtitle spacing.

I already had switched to the new material components (androidx). So the issue is still present in latest version.

Using the solution of a combination of `wrap_content` as height and the `actionBarSize` attribute as `minHeight` doesn't affect devices without the issue, so on those, no jumping will be visible.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:actionBarSize" />
```

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you to create a new layout for toolbar and then you can fill it
however you want to.And set it as ActionBar in java code. Therefore, you will not face any space problem anymore.

Comment: thanks for reply, but I try to understand why it happens, yes i can create a layout and fill it, it is not a problem

Comment: Most probably, it happens for standart height size of ActionBar that defined by Android. In this code;

android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"

Answer (score 0):

The **problem** is that you have specified the **layout height as ?attr/actionBarSize**. This should be fine if you were not specifying a subtitle as this is tailor made for title only. My suggestion is to make `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` and instead use the `minHeight` parameter of the toolbar. Hence your xml becomes-

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
app:theme="@style/MyToolBar">
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use a custom font (NotosanJP) for my project so my `Toolbar` sub title is cut of. Without using a custom font, it works well.
So my solution is to change the text size in`Toolbar`.
After debug, I found that **the default size** of my current `Toolbar` title is 20 and `Toolbar` subtitle is 16. So I reduce it by 2

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            ...
            app:titleTextAppearance="@style/MyToolbarTitleAppearance"
            app:subtitleTextAppearance="@style/MyToolbarSubtitleAppearance" />
```

**style.xml**

```
<style name="MyToolbarTitleAppearance" parent="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
    <item name="android:textSize">18dp</item>
</style>

<style name="MyToolbarSubtitleAppearance" parent="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Subtitle">
    <item name="android:textSize">14dp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what the accepted answer suggests, adding `android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"`, I'd also suggest you add a bottom padding. In my case, if I didn't do it, depending on the system font size, the subtitle was almost cut by the end of the toolbar. If you have the space, just add `android:paddingBottom="6dp"`